# Delete a pointer in the main file

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have a class `T`, defined a destructor of `T` and try to define the `+` operator.

How do I suppose to delete `t2`?

or should I return the value of `T` from the function in another way?

```
T& T::operator + (const T& t1)
{
    T* t2 = new T;
    t2 = this + t1;
    return *t2;
}

void main()
{
    T t1(1,2), t2(3,8);
    cout << (t1 + t2) << endl;
}
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: See [this](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html).

Comment: `operator +` should return a `T`, and you should not be using `new` and `delete`. What is the definition of `T`?

Comment: This line: `t2 = this + t1;` is changing the value of the pointer…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need pointers here. Use objects. The usual idiom is to provide `operator+=` as a member function and `operator+` as a free function:

```
class T {
public:
    T& operator+=(const T& t) {
        // do whatever you need to do to add `t` to `*this`
    return *this;
}

T operator+(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    return T(lhs) += rhs;
}
```

Comment: why not pass `lhs` by value in this case?

Comment: @DavidBrown - six of one, half a dozen of the other.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do this (probably at all).

What you want to do is create a temporary containing the correct value, and return that:

```
T T::operator+(const T& t1) const { 
    return value + t1.value;
}
```

For the typical case (where you want to allow conversions of the left operand) you probably want to use a free function:

```
T operator+(T const &a, T const &b) { 
    return T(a.val + b.val);
}
```

Note that unless `T::val` is public (usually a poor idea) this will probably need to be a friend of T.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I'd return `const T` as this feels more correct in context of binary operator semantics. For instance, it prevents writing things like: `(a + b) = c`.

Comment: @Haroogan:  Returning const T will prevent pass-by-move.  This idiom was questionable before C++11, but it's pretty much always a bad idea since.